# how to fix "'Tagify' is declared but its value is never read" error?

Tags: javascript, tagify

I'm trying to use Tagify in my project but either the document is not clear about how to use it or I'm the worst person when it comes to JS. I added the `import Tagify from '@yaireo/tagify';` in my `app.js` and compiled it with no error but then I returned to the `app.js` i got the IDE warning of `'Tagify' is declared but its value is never read` and I have no idea what should I do about this. also in the console `i get the Uncaught ReferenceError: Tagify is not defined` error.

also, I'm using the following script in my blade file to use the tagify on a textbox:

```
<script>
        var input = document.querySelector('textarea[name=webskills]'),
            tagify = new Tagify(input, {
                enforceWhitelist : true,
                delimiters       : null,
                whitelist        : ["The Shawshank Redemption", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", "The Dark Knight", "12 Angry Men", "Schindler's List", "Pulp Fiction",],
                callbacks        : {
                    add    : console.log,  // callback when adding a tag
                    remove : console.log   // callback when removing a tag
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you're missing a few details about how you're bundling app.js and whether/how you're including it in your page.

Comment: im bundling my app.js like this and except tagify everything else is working. also im including it in my page like `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` and everything is working as it should be except this one. i guess you're right. not sure how to include tagify in my bundle.
`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
require ('./bootstrap');
var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks");
Turbolinks.start();
import Tagify from '@yaireo/tagify';`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `tagify = new Tagify(...` if you don't use `tagify` variable, simply write:

```js
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector('textarea[name=webskills]')

  new Tagify(input, {
                enforceWhitelist : true,
                delimiters       : null,
                whitelist        : ["The Shawshank Redemption", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", "The Dark Knight", "12 Angry Men", "Schindler's List", "Pulp Fiction",],
                callbacks        : {
                    add    : console.log,  // callback when adding a tag
                    remove : console.log   // callback when removing a tag
                }
            })
</script>
```

This warning you are seeing can be safely ignored as irrelevant.